# How can I save this JSON to a mongoDB database serviced by MonogDB Compass?

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, mongoose, bson

I have some raw JSON that I have populated for testing purposes, but now I would like to put it into a mongoDB database using mongoDB Compass.

My mongoDB connection string is working and I have working mongoose code.

How do I go about doing this?

I would hope this would be an easy task as mongoDB stores it's data in the form of BSON already.

Here is a snippet of my code.

```
const json_string = 
`[
  {
    "link":    "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BMOjVYgYaG8",
    "image":   "https://i.imgur.com/Z0yVBpO.png",
    "title":   "Debunking the paelo diet with Christina Warinner",
    // ... snip
  },
  { // ... snip
```

The schema is already created:

```
// for relevant data from google profile
schema.Article = new Schema({ 
  link:       { type: String, required: true  },
  image:      { type: String, required: true  },
  title:      { type: String, required: true  },
  summary:    { type: String, required: true  },
  tag:        { type: String, required: true  },
  domain:     { type: String, required: true  }, 
  date:       { type: String, required: true  },   
  timestamp:  { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});
```

Comment: MongoDB doesn't store its data in JSON!  It stores structured data, yes, but JSON is a string representation of this structure... and your database definitely isn't (or shouldn't be) a pile of strings.

Comment: Apparently it is BSON, which is similar ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSON ... updated

Answer (score 2):

You can use this

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI);

const articleSchema = new Schema({
  link: { type: String, required: true },
  image: { type: String, required: true },
  title: { type: String, required: true },
  summary: { type: String, required: true },
  tag: { type: String, required: true },
  domain: { type: String, required: true },
  date: { type: String, required: true },
  timestamp: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});

const Article = mongoose.model("Article", articleSchema);

const json_string = `[
  {
    "link":    "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BMOjVYgYaG8",
    "image":   "https://i.imgur.com/Z0yVBpO.png",
    "title":   "Debunking the paelo diet with Christina Warinner"
  }
]`;
const jsonBody = JSON.parse(json_string);

for (let i = 0; i < jsonBody.length; i++) {
  const data = jsonBody[i];
  const article = new Article({
    link: data.link,
    image: data.image,
    title: data.title
    //.... rest
  });
  article.save();
}
```

1. Convert JSON string to an array
2. Loop through each object in the array
3. Create a new Article instance based on values from the object
4. Call the save method on the Article object

Comment: In my syntax I am using `new Schema ({ ... // someSchema })` , curious as to the difference, and is there a reference?

Comment: @chris edited answer, what do yo mean by "is there a reference?"??

Comment: Per your answer edit ... so that was a typo I take it, using `new Schema()` is the correct way?

Comment: there is no definite correct answer as both methods are accepted & correct!

Comment: Can you reference this information from Mongoose ... I am looking for it currently.

Comment: my first answer was similar to this https://mongoosejs.com/ and then the edited answer similar to this https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html

Comment: Yes, but the Schema constructor is doing something.  Isn't it more responsible to know what it is doing.  It is an actual function that is running at construction time!